# What happens when the MOSFET isn't conducting, circuit-wise?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAWQdg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For **Vin** below threshold voltage, M1 isn't conducting, neither does M2 since Id=0. So what happens circuit wise, how come that **Vdd=Vout** ( we did this in class)?

Comment: Think about it in very simple terms. PMOS conducts, while NMOS doesn't. So it's same as Vout is connected to VDD and disconnected from GND.

Comment: More importantly you have to understand, what is transistor.

Comment: You do NOT know the current through M2, unless you know what is connected to Vout.

Comment: If M2 is "on", consider what would happen if Vout was not equal to Vdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that M1 is N channel while M2 is P channel, although they both invert from gate to drain in this configuration.

With Vin at 0, M1 is off.  With the gate of M2 at 0, M2 is presumably on.  I say "presumably" since you have provided no specs on Vdd and the required gate voltage for M2 to be on.  I'm assuming these have been arranged such that a P channel FET with source tied to Vdd is on when its gate is at 0 V.

From above, replace M1 with a open switch and M2 with a closed switch.  Vout is now obvious.  Draw it out as open/closed switches if that helps you see it.

Comment: You presumed correctly. But I am having hard time figuring out why is M2 closed and M1 open, since both of its currents are 0.

Comment: It's because this one is M2 is on, right?

Comment: @rkc: FETs are voltage controlled not current controlled.  Current doesn't matter toward open/closed switch behavior.  It's the gate-source voltage that matters.

Comment: @rkcepelin - But pretend, just for a moment, that there was a load on the output. Now consider that M1 has leakage current (which it does). What does this do to the output?

Comment: @rkcepelin, Even if you think about a mechanical switch, it can be closed and still have no current flowing through it if the external circuit doesn't provide any current.